# How to completely change my email?

Tags: support, login

My main account is only available to me under an old Yahoo email address (yikes), that I do not ever use anymore. Whenever I need to sign in and get to this account, I need to do it with Yahoo. I want to change my email and be able to log in with that new email and have it point to this account. How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the new email isn't from Yahoo, follow the instructions [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190442/myopenid-shuts-down-february-1-2014-add-an-alternative-login-method-to-your-ac). (They're written with MyOpenID in mind, but the principles are the same.)

If the new email is from Yahoo, the easiest thing to do is set up third-party ID using the above method, remove your old login, and then add the new one.

You can also sign up for [Stack Exchange OpenID](http://openid.stackexchange.com) using any email you wish and add it to your account.