# Simple email address login + account deletion issues

Tags: support, login

I know I might be facing some "TL;DR" remarks, but please bear with me.

As a follow up to a question I asked to this site's support team, and to explain my problem properly, I'll go with the recipe method :

- Create an account with the email ***temporary_email[at]something.etc***, name the user ***"Temporary Account"***
- Now change your account name to ***"Something else"***
- You may also change the email address

A) First question, why can't I update the email address which serves as login? Changing the email address is simply useless as I can't login with it.

- So, as I could not edit the email address which serves as login, I used the Google login option with the email ***some_g00gl3_account[at]....etc*** and then deleted the StackExchange login from *"my logins"*

B) Second question, is it possible to delete the Google login option and get back to a simple address login? (I saw [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261734/how-do-completely-change-my-email) but it doesn't explain why)

- Now let's jump to the weirdest part:

First let's recap :

- We changed our email address, AND removed it from "my logins" PLUS we changed our account name

C) So why when I tried to login in with the old login ***temporary_email[at]something.etc*** is the login page proposing me to create an account named ***"Something else"***??

Not weird enough?

Okay then let's accept the account creation, and now what you do is click the delete account button in my profile... Thought all your infos where deleted? Haha no just login with the ***temporary_email[at]something.etc*** address, and we're back to step C)

Stackoverflow indeed...

- Oh and by the way, connect to your account named ***"Something else"***, you will see a message from StackOverflow welcoming you to the site... again

I just wanted to change the email address with which I signed up...

And if you're wondering why I would like to change my email address, it's simply because when I create an account on a website, I always sign up using a temporary email address, and if I'm interested in said-site, I update my infos on the site in order to have a permanent account. This is the first time I'm facing this kind of trouble.

Don't get me wrong, I truly believe that StackOverflow is really a great site with a wonderful community, this post is just me explaining my problem more clearly (I hope)

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A) The email address you enter in your profile page is not used for logging in. It is used for account recovery and finding your account when you attempt to contact Stack Exchange support. The **only** thing that is used to log you in are the accounts listed under "my logins" which is why you have to have at least one on your account.

B) Yes, you can add any login method you want. My guess, though, is that you want to re-add the Stack Exchange OpenID login, but under a new email address. Unfortunately [it is not possible to change your email on a Stack Exchange OpenID](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/102469). You would have to [create a new Stack Exchange OpenID](https://openid.stackexchange.com/account/register) with your new email address in order to do that.

C) I'm guessing that you still have your old Stack Exchange OpenID email address set in the email field on your Stack Overflow profile. There is an automated account recovery process in place to prevent users accidentally creating duplicate accounts. When you attempt to login / create a new account with your Stack Exchange OpenID, it is seeing that your email is already present on another account and automatically connecting you back to that account and asking you if it's yours.

Comment: What if our email account closes or gets deleted by our organisation?

Comment: So if I set my Stack Exchange OpenID to email1@example1.com, I can create a new one with email2@example2.com, and set my login to that one?