# Stack Overflow: Remove Facebook login, add email login

Tags: support

I have a login to Stack Overflow via Facebook. Now I would like to delete my Facebook account, and that means I wouldn't be able to login to SO any more.

Went to this URL to add email login (and remove Facebook login):

`https://stackoverflow.com/users/mylogins/{your user id on SO}`

That page offers me to add Google login (plus Yahoo, AOL and a few more), but no option to add an email address to login with that.

What am I missing?

Comment: Sorry to follow you over here, but [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261734/how-do-completely-change-my-email?rq=1) may be the answer to your question.

Comment: Appreciate your help